# $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$(Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose that the order of $N$ and index of $N$ in $G$ are co-prime. Prove that $\{x|x\in G ;x^{|N|}=e\}$ is a normal subgroup of $N$.

Comment: I could prove that the set is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: And what part of that proof doesn't immediately carry over to $N$?

Comment: How do I prove that its a subgroup of $N$?

Comment: Good, that's the real thing you have to prove.  For that you need to use the assumptions on $|N|$ and $[G:N]$.  And the definition of the subgroup in question.  You may also ask yourself: which elements of $N$ can you easily establish are in this set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** There exists $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a|N|+b|G/N|=1$.

**Hint 2:** $x^{|G/N|}\in N$ for any $x\in G$. (This statement is always true.)

Assume $x^{|N|}=e$. Can you see why Hints 1 and 2 imply $x\in N$?

Comment: How do I prove Hint 2?

Comment: @Grobber: Apply Lagrange's Theorem to the quotient group $G/N$.

Comment: Yeah, I got the proof of Hint 2. I can also prove that $x\in N$. But how to conclude the result?

Comment: @Grobber: Sorry, I corrected a typo. So assuming $x^{|N|}=e$, we use Hints 1 and 2 to prove $x\in N$. This shows that $\{x|x\in G ;x^{|N|}=e\}\subseteq N$. You already know how to show the subgroup is normal. And that's it! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the set $\{x\in G :  x^{|N|}=e\}$.

Suppose $x\notin N$ then, $xN\neq eN \in G/N$.

Then...... ?